# TheGraph: one graph-node for several blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, thegraph

`graph-node` from [TheGraph](https://thegraph.com/) can get data from blockchain.

From https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

```
cargo run -p graph-node --release -- \
  --postgres-url postgresql://<USERNAME><:PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/<POSTGRES_DB_NAME> \
  --ethereum-rpc <ETHEREUM_NETWORK_NAME>:https://mainnet.infura.io \
  --ipfs 127.0.0.1:5001 \
  --debug
```

So running with `--ethereum-rpc mainnet:https://mainnet.infura.io`

**But how to have one `graph-node` to several blockchains, e.g. one Ethereum mainnet and one Ethereum testnet ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple `--ethereum-rpc` in the command

e.g.

```bash
cargo run -p graph-node --release -- \
  --postgres-url postgresql://<USERNAME><:PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/<POSTGRES_DB_NAME> \
  --ethereum-rpc mainnet:https://mainnet.infura.io \
  --ethereum-rpc goerli:https://...
  --ipfs 127.0.0.1:5001 \
  --debug
```

Ref: https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/pull/1027